# In each of the following cases determine whether the given set is convex (but not strictly convex), strictly convex or not convex.?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let K be a subset of the plane. It is said to be convex if given any two
points in K, the line segment joining them is also contained in K. It is said
to be strictly convex if given any two points in K, the mid-point of the line
segment joining them lies in the interior of K. In each of the following cases
determine whether the given set is convex (but not strictly convex), strictly
convex or not convex.

(a) K = {(x, y) | x^2 + y^2  ≤ 1}

(b) K = {(x, y) | |x| + |y| ≤ 1}.

(c) K = {(x, y) | x^2/3 + y^2/3 ≤ 1}.

my attempt   : 
option. a )It is not strictly convex  but it is convex due to bounded set.

option. b) It is  strictly convex because if we plot graph on xy axis it will  give rhombus shape that is strictly convex..

option. c) it is not strictly convex but it is convex due to bounded set.

Is my answer is correct or not i would be more thankful who rectifying my mistake

Answer (score 0):

a) The conclusion is correct, but "due to bounded set" means nothing. Plenty of bounded non-convex sets out there - for instance, (c).

b) The conclusion is wrong. This set is convex and not strictly convex **because** it is a rhombus (and, specifically, a square) in the plane.

c) It is not convex. Specifically, consider the segment joining $(0,1)$ with $(1,0)$.

Comment: thanks ,,,but  im not getting option b)   how can u claim that rhombus is not strictly convex,,, @ G . Sassatelli

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh, for b) if you take two points on the border of the rhombus and connect them, the line segment (including its midpoint) stays on the border (not inside it).

Comment: thanks a lot  now im getting opt b) @   farruhota,,,but  option c is convex or not pliz tell me ,,im still confuse

Comment: im not getting ,im asking option C) x^2/3 + y^2/3 ≤ 1  ........this  is convex or not @ farruhota

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh, wait a minute, do you mean: $(x^2)/3+(y^2)/3\le 1$ (strictly convex) or $x^{(2/3)}+y^{(2/3)}\le 1$ (not convex, see here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=draw+x%5E(2%2F3)%2By%5E(2%2F3)%3C%3D1)?

Comment: thanks u so much ..what a beautiful diagram,, now i understand clearly  @ farruhota..

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh, you are welcome. I see you are a new user, once you get the full answer, you should accept it. Good luck.

Comment: Isn't (a) a strictly convex set?